# How to update a platform with qualified upgraded members

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My name is Francis,  I'm from Nigeria. I'm also new to web development using *Php*, *Javascript* and *Ajax*.

My problem is lengthy but I will try to make it shorter and concise enough for easy assimilation.

I'm currently working on a project which has the attributes of **MLM** (*Multi Level Marketing*). In this same project, the platform required is a *5 by 5 Forced Matrix scheme*,  which entails that a single member has a limit of *registering 5 direct members* and which in turn makes him to have an additional *25 indirect members* from his *initial 5 direct members*.

The project is designed to be progressive using the *infant loop scheme* whereby,  on the cycles are to be incremented in infinite loop leaving only stages of a cycle to a list of 5 stages.

This means that for every Cycle, there's a limit of 5 stages.
And before a member would be transversed onto another stage, he or she must have had a certain amount for the upgrade and thus be upgraded if the amount is checked.

The problem I'm having now is the algorithm to be used to accomplish this.
Mind you, in this same project,  when a member first registers, he or she is automatically placed under stage 1 of Cycle 1. And there by, when he or she pays a certain amount of money again, he or she gets upgraded to stage 2 of cycle 1. But the issue now is this,

How do I continue from stage 2 through stage 5 and back to stage 1 in every cycle?

I don't know how to place the iteration and I don't how the iteration counter would come about.

Thank you very much for reading.

Your answers would be overly appreciated.

Below is the code i have written so far..
This was implemented in the Add Member Button..

```
//############################################################################################################################################################################################
//This script will be used for the Statistics implementation...
//Update the Cycle Table and add Members...
//Search Through the Leader's Cycle Table and fetch all details.....
$searchLeader = "SELECT * FROM cycle WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Sponsor_ID'] . "' AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Sponsor_Name'] . "'";
$findQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $searchLeader) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$rows=mysqli_num_rows($findQuery); if($rows > 0){
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findQuery)) {
        //Hold the Database fields of his five direct Members....
        $LeaderMember1 = $result['Direct_Member1_ID'];
        $LeaderMember2 = $result['Direct_Member2_ID'];
        $LeaderMember3 = $result['Direct_Member3_ID'];
        $LeaderMember4 = $result['Direct_Member4_ID'];
        $LeaderMember5 = $result['Direct_Member5_ID'];
        $_SESSION['LeaderCycles'] = $result['Cycles'];
        $_SESSION['LeaderStages'] = $result['Stages'];

        //............search through the Member's Cycle Table and get the details..............................................................
        if ($LeaderMember1 == $_SESSION['Member_ID']) {//if The Member ID Matches with the First Direct Member of the Leader..
            $searchMembers = "SELECT * FROM member_cycle WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Member_ID'] . "'";
            $execute = mysqli_query($conn, $searchMembers) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $countDm = mysqli_num_rows($execute);
            if ($countDm > 0) {//if a record is found in the cycle Table...then...
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)) {//loop throught the result set and fetch all the data;
                    //assign Database records to php variable names...
                    $Direct_Member1_ID = $result['Direct_Member1_ID'];
                    $DM1_Name = $result['DM1_Name'];
                    $Direct_Member2_ID = $result['Direct_Member2_ID'];
                    $DM2_Name = $result['DM2_Name'];
                    $Direct_Member3_ID = $result['Direct_Member3_ID'];
                    $DM3_Name = $result['DM3_Name'];
                    $Direct_Member4_ID = $result['Direct_Member4_ID'];
                    $DM4_Name = $result['DM4_Name'];
                    $Direct_Member5_ID = $result['Direct_Member5_ID'];
                    $DM5_Name = $result['DM5_Name'];
                    $Stages = $result['Stages'];
                    $Cycles = $result['Cycles'];

                    //.................................................................................................................................................
                    //Test against any empty field and populate if found...
                    if (empty($Direct_Member1_ID) && empty($DM1_Name) && $Cycles == 1 && $Stages == 1) { //Add Member to Member Earning Table...
                        $addMemberEarningTbl="INSERT INTO member_earning_tbl ( Sponsor_ID, Direct_Member_ID, Direct_Members, Direct_Member_Activation, DM_Activation_Profit, Total_Generated_Revenue, Available_Balance ) VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['Member_ID']."', '".$Member_ID."', '".$Surname."', '1000', '500', '500', '500' )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMemberEarningTbl) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add a Member to the First Direct member Position in the Member cycle Table...
                        $addMember1 = "UPDATE member_cycle SET 
                                        Direct_Member1_ID='" . $Member_ID . "',
                                        DM1_Name='" . $Surname . "'
                                        WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "'
                                        AND Member_Name='" . $Sponsor . "'
                                        AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "'
                                        AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add Member to Leader's first Indirect Member cycle table
                        $addIndirectMember1 = "UPDATE cycle SET 
                                                IM_1='" . $Surname . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                                AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "' 
                                                AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "' AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addIndirectMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Deduct the Upgrade Figure (2000) from the Member Temp Table...
                        $deduct = "UPDATE member_upgrade_counter SET 
                                    DM_Count='1',
                                    total=total - '2000'  
                                    WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $deduct) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Share Member Upgrade Profit  (50% 2000) to Leader...
                        $addLeaderProfit = "UPDATE leader_reg_tbl SET
                                            DM_Total_Revenue= DM_Total_Revenue + '" . $leader_dm_profit . "', 
                                            Total_Earned_Cash= Total_Earned_Cash + '" . $leader_dm_profit . "', 
                                            Total_Balance= Total_Balance + '" . $leader_dm_profit . "'
                                            WHERE Transaction_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addLeaderProfit) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add Member's Upgrade amount ( 50% of #2000) to Platform..
                        $addPlatformProfit = "UPDATE platform_earning_tbl SET Member_Total_Revenue= Member_Total_Revenue + '" . $platform_dm_profit . "',
                                                Balance=Balance + '" . $platform_dm_profit . "' 
                                                WHERE Leader_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addPlatformProfit) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Upgrade Member to Stage 2 of Cycle 1....
                        $upGradeMember1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO member_cycle
                                            ( 
                                            Member_ID,
                                            Member_Name,
                                            Cycles,
                                            Stages,
                                            Upgrade_Amount
                                            )
                                            VALUES
                                            (
                                            '" . $Sponsor_ID . "',
                                            '" . $Sponsor . "',
                                            '" . 1 . "',
                                            '" . 2 . "',
                                            '3000'
                                            )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $upGradeMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //update Member1 to Leader Direct Member1 in stage 2....
                        $updateLeaderCycle = "UPDATE cycle SET 
                                                Direct_Member1_ID='" . $_SESSION['Member_ID'] . "',
                                                DM1_Name='" . $_SESSION['Surname'] . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "'
                                                AND Cycles='1' AND Stages='2'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $updateLeaderCycle) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Below codes Elevates the Leader to Stage 3 of Cycle 1.....
                        $searchLeader1 = "SELECT DM1_Name, DM2_Name, DM3_Name, DM4_Name, DM5_Name
                                            FROM cycle WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                            AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "'
                                            AND Cycles='1' 
                                            AND Stages='2'";
                        $findQuery1 = mysqli_query($conn, $searchLeader1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        while ($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($findQuery1))  {
                            $DM1_Name=$result1['DM1_Name'];
                            $DM2_Name=$result1['DM2_Name'];
                            $DM3_Name=$result1['DM3_Name'];
                            $DM4_Name=$result1['DM4_Name'];
                            $DM5_Name=$result1['DM5_Name'];

                            if (empty($DM1_Name) && empty($DM2_Name) && empty($DM3_Name) && empty($DM4_Name) && empty($DM5_Name)) {
                                //Upgrade the Leader to Stage 3 of Cycle 1...
                                $UpgradeLeader = "INSERT IGNORE INTO cycle
                                                    (
                                                    Member_ID, 
                                                    Member_Name, 
                                                    Cycles, 
                                                    Stages
                                                    )
                                                    VALUES
                                                    (
                                                    '" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] ."',
                                                    '" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "',
                                                    '1',
                                                    '3'
                                                    )";
                                mysqli_query($conn, $UpgradeLeader) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //...............................................................................................................................................
                    elseif (empty($Direct_Member2_ID) && empty($DM2_Name) && $Cycles == 1 && $Stages == 1) {//If the second direct Member is empty
                        //Add Member to Member Earning Table...
                        $addMemberEarningTbl="INSERT INTO member_earning_tbl ( Sponsor_ID, Direct_Member_ID, Direct_Members, Direct_Member_Activation, DM_Activation_Profit, Total_Generated_Revenue, Available_Balance ) VALUES ( '".$_SESSION['Member_ID']."', '".$Member_ID."', '".$Surname."', '1000', '500', '500', '500' )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMemberEarningTbl) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        //Add a Member to the First Direct member Position in the Member cycle Table...
                        $addMember2 = "UPDATE member_cycle SET Direct_Member2_ID='" . $Member_ID . "', DM2_Name='" . $Surname . "' WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "' AND Member_Name='" . $Sponsor . "' AND Cycles='" . 1 . "' AND Stages='" . 1 . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMember2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add Member to Leader's first Indirect Member cycle table
                        $addIndirectMember1 = "UPDATE cycle SET IM_6='" . $Surname . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                                AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "' 
                                                AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "' AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addIndirectMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                    }

                    //...............................................................................................................................................
                    elseif (empty($Direct_Member3_ID) && empty($DM3_Name) && $Cycles == 1 && $Stages == 1) {
                        //Add Member to Member Earning Table...
                        $addMemberEarningTbl="INSERT INTO member_earning_tbl
                                                (
                                                Sponsor_ID,
                                                Direct_Member_ID,
                                                Direct_Members,
                                                Direct_Member_Activation,
                                                DM_Activation_Profit,
                                                Total_Generated_Revenue,
                                                Available_Balance
                                                ) 
                                                VALUES
                                                (
                                                '".$_SESSION['Member_ID']."',
                                                '".$Member_ID."',
                                                '".$Surname."',
                                                '1000',
                                                '500',
                                                '500',
                                                '500'
                                                )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMemberEarningTbl) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add a Member to the First Direct member Position in the Member cycle Table...
                        $addMember3 = "UPDATE member_cycle SET 
                                        Direct_Member3_ID='" . $Member_ID . "',
                                        DM3_Name='" . $Surname . "'
                                        WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "'
                                        AND Member_Name='" . $Sponsor . "'
                                        AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "'
                                        AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add Member to Leader's first Indirect Member cycle table
                        $addIndirectMember1 = "UPDATE cycle SET IM_11='" . $Surname . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                                AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "' 
                                                AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "' AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addIndirectMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                    }

                    //...............................................................................................................................................
                    elseif (empty($Direct_Member4_ID) && empty($DM4_Name) && $Cycles == 1 && $Stages == 1) {
                        //Add Member to Member Earning Table...
                        $addMemberEarningTbl="INSERT INTO member_earning_tbl
                                                (
                                                Sponsor_ID,
                                                Direct_Member_ID,
                                                Direct_Members,
                                                Direct_Member_Activation,
                                                DM_Activation_Profit,
                                                Total_Generated_Revenue,
                                                Available_Balance
                                                ) 
                                                VALUES
                                                (
                                                '".$_SESSION['Member_ID']."',
                                                '".$Member_ID."',
                                                '".$Surname."',
                                                '1000',
                                                '500',
                                                '500',
                                                '500'
                                                )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMemberEarningTbl) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add a Member to the First Direct member Position in the Member cycle Table...
                        $addMember4 = "UPDATE member_cycle SET 
                                        Direct_Member4_ID='" . $Member_ID . "',
                                        DM4_Name='" . $Surname . "'
                                        WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "'
                                        AND Member_Name='" . $Sponsor . "'
                                        AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "'
                                        AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";

                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        //Add Member to Leader's first Indirect Member cycle table
                        $addIndirectMember1 = "UPDATE cycle SET IM_16='" . $Surname . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                                AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "' 
                                                AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "' AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addIndirectMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                    }
                    //...............................................................................................................................................
                    else {//Add the Fifth Direct Member of Member
                        //Add Member to Member Earning Table...
                        $addMemberEarningTbl="INSERT INTO member_earning_tbl
                                                (
                                                Sponsor_ID,
                                                Direct_Member_ID,
                                                Direct_Members,
                                                Direct_Member_Activation,
                                                DM_Activation_Profit,
                                                Total_Generated_Revenue,
                                                Available_Balance
                                                ) 
                                                VALUES
                                                (
                                                '".$_SESSION['Member_ID']."',
                                                '".$Member_ID."',
                                                '".$Surname."',
                                                '1000',
                                                '500',
                                                '500',
                                                '500'
                                                )";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMemberEarningTbl) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add a Member to the First Direct member Position in the Member cycle Table...
                        $addMember1 = "UPDATE member_cycle SET 
                                        Direct_Member5_ID='" . $Member_ID . "',
                                        DM5_Name='" . $Surname . "'
                                        WHERE Member_ID='" . $Sponsor_ID . "'
                                        AND Member_Name='" . $Sponsor . "'
                                        AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "'
                                        AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                        //Add Member to Leader's first Indirect Member cycle table
                        $addIndirectMember1 = "UPDATE cycle SET IM_21='" . $Surname . "'
                                                WHERE Member_ID='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader_ID'] . "' 
                                                AND Member_Name='" . $_SESSION['Union_Leader'] . "' 
                                                AND Cycles='" . $cycle . "' AND Stages='" . $stage . "'";
                        mysqli_query($conn, $addIndirectMember1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //...............................................................................................................................................
```

Comment: I've been reading your question several times, but it's just to _unclear_. I think it will be best if you show us the code you have as it will most likely clear things up for us.

Comment: Ok sir...  let me work on it .

Comment: The Comment length isnt enough to convey my codes

Comment: Don't try to comment your code. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46686391/edit) your question and add the code to it.

Comment: i have updated my question with the relevant codes used...

Comment: This is just a wall of code with almost no explanation. It also needs formatting properly please. Try to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example which just includes the parts of the code which are relevant to your question or problem. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some guidance. No-one is going to see and read this mountain of stuff to try and understand what's happening, it will take too long. Imagine you're asking a busy colleague for help - summarise the issue, don't make them code-review your whole application

Comment: Also one other thing from reading the text - " the cycles are to be incremented in infinite loop". Infinite loops are a very bad thing and always cause an application to crash. Are you sure that's what you mean? Your description of your requirements is not really very clear. Can you re-word it? An example using some sample data would probably also help people to comprehend what you're asking for.

Comment: Did my best to fix the code formatting, but that wall of text was hard to go through.

Comment: I'm sorry for the Un formatted text. .@ADyson... yes its meant to be an infinite loop where by on the cycles would be incremented after exactly 5 stages of one cycle have been archived by a particular member

Comment: Please check your understanding of the word "infinite". An infinite loop goes on forever and never stops at any time. By definition, an infinite loop will make your application un-usable, because the code which contains the infinite loop will never return.

Comment: Example:

 

$counter=1;

$ cycle=1;

while ($counter>=1){

if ($amount>=3000){

//deduct amount from member table

//add member to stage 3 of cycle X

//add member to his sponsor's direct member filed on stage 2 cycle X

//add member to Leader's indirect member filed.

}

if ($counter>=6){

$counter=0;

}

$cycle++;

}

}

Comment: Above code is a snippet of what I intend to archive.. The stages would count from 1-5 where as,  the cycles would count from 1- x> 0

Comment: ok well that's not infinite because there's a possibility for $counter to be set to 0 and break the while condition. Perhaps you meant " infant loop scheme" which you referred to earlier in the text - was "infinite" a typo when you meant "infant", by any chance?

Comment: Anyway there's still far too much code to comprehend what is happening and the description is still a bit garbled. Try to describe the process clearly, maybe using bullet points for each stage, and a worked example showing input and desired output. Also comment your code to show which part of the process it implements (or tries to implement), and whether you think it works or not. I still have very little idea what you're actually trying to achieve. If you were my customer and you gave me that as your list of requirements I would ask you to re-write it as well.

Comment: Wow... This is gonna be rather too much for me now. I will have to get a good explanation as to what I really wish to implement.  But then, how would an infant loop work on php server. Currently,  I'm still running on localhost server. How do do I implement and infant loop and it would run regardless of whether or not the user is active?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by an "infant loop"? I've never come across that concept before. Is there somewhere I can read about it online? And why would it matter if you're on localhost or a remote server? (N.B. If you're on localhost and executing PHP code from a browser, then localhost is already running a webserver with PHP installed). Are you actually talking about an automated background service, triggered by something like cron or Windows Scheduled tasks, which performs the same job repeatedly at set intervals of time?

Comment: It could have been a typo error. .. i meant to say infinite loop, where by only the said cycle would be incremented after a stage has reached its minimum number of 5.... i just wanted a counter that would be implemented for loop even if the session is destroyed . The counter would be tested against the amount of every member for their upgrades .

Comment: sounds like you need to persist your value in a database, if you need to keep a count of something in between user sessions.

Comment: Ok... i would be delighted if you gave a clue of that..

Comment: from your code it looks like you're already familiar with how to save things in databases?

Comment: Yes.. I'm familiar with saving things in database. ..All I needed was an algorithm to solve my predicament